# AsyncTask dont show me message from server (HttpUrlConnection)

Tags: java, android

So I'm trying to read a message from the server by HttpURLConnection in a AsyncTask class. The problem is, when i send the request to read the data from the server, it just keeps displaying the ProgresssDialog, like it doesn't read the data from the server:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

EditText name, password;
Button login;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);


    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String serverURL = "http://192.168.1.1/my/text.php";
            LongOperation longOperation = new LongOperation();
            longOperation.execute(serverURL);


        }
    });



}

private class LongOperation  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {



    private String content;
    private String error = null;
    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

    TextView uiUpdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        uiUpdate.setText("Output : ");
        dialog.setMessage("Downloading source..");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            HttpURLConnection client = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            client.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = client.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            content = bufferedReader.readLine();

            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            client.disconnect();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            error = e.getMessage();
        }

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        dialog.dismiss();

        if (error != null) {

            uiUpdate.setText("Output : "+error);

        } else {

            uiUpdate.setText("Output : "+content);

        }
    }
```

I already tryed before the connectivity to server via HttpClient, so thats not the problem.Thanks!

Comment: I am commenting here because its not the answer to your question but a suggestion. Use Retrofit for web api calls. It'll make your life easier.

Comment: why is the onPostExecute param a click listener, yet it's defined as an AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>

Comment: You should use `@Override` Annotations in the asyncTask, too. That way you'll notice the error ;-)

Comment: Do some logging with the Log class and see if the onPostExecute is being called.
And also, the Java convention for naming is that instances start with lowercase, using Dialog instead of dialog might be confusing for other developers.

Comment: The comment from @Lucas shows the problem.  It's never getting into your onPostExecute() method because it's not correctly overriding the onPostExecute() of your AsyncTask.  It's a good idea to add `@Override` before each of the override methods, that way the IDE will tell you if there are problems.  To fix it, just define it as `onPostExecute(Void unused)`

Comment: Thank you very much guys, it worked. Changing the parameter in the onPostExecute method to void, and using @Override fixed the problem. If somebody want to make a answer from the comment, i will gladly accept it.

Comment: This issue may due to client is not connecting to server. May be your server is not up. Try set requestTimeOut

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging it and see if OnPostExecute() method is getting called or not.!

This seems to get stuck in your stream reader code. Also, add a connection timeout of, say, 5-10 seconds for better user experience.!

Moreover, there seems to be an issue with your return type of doInBackground() method and input parameter type of OnPostExecute() method. As per your AsyncTask definition, they both should be string, isnt it?

Comment: I think that the doInBackground() method is the one failing to read the data, but i already have tryed everything possible, but i still dont get the result, hope for somebody that knows how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

[See this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

Try remove `client.connect();`

```
  try {
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            HttpURLConnection client = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            //remove client.connect();

int response = client.getResponse();

if(response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
 InputStream inputStream = client.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            content = bufferedReader.readLine();

            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
}

    finally{
                client.disconnect();
    }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            error = e.getMessage();
        }

        return null;
```

Make sure your server is running. Also set request time out.

You are not always required to explicitly call the connect method to initiate the connection. Operations that depend on being connected, like getInputStream, getOutputStream will implicitly perform the connection, when necessary.

This [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/connecting.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private class LongOperation  extends                    AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
private String content;
private String error = null;
private ProgressDialog dialog = new        ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
TextView uiUpdate = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.output);
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
uiUpdate.setText("Output : ");
dialog.setMessage("Downloading source..");
dialog.show();
}

@Override
protected Strinh doInBackground(String... urls) {
try {
URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
HttpURLConnection client =   (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();     client.connect();
InputStream inputStream = client.getInputStream();
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new       BufferedReader(new     InputStreamReader(inputStream));
content = bufferedReader.readLine();
bufferedReader.close();
inputStream.close();
//client.discon dialog.dismiss();
} 
catch (IOException e)
{
content = e.getMessage();
}

return content ;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String returnValue) {

if (return value != null) {

uiUpdate.setText("Output : "+error);
} 
else {
uiUpdate.setText("Output No Value Returned");
}
dialog.dismiss();
}
```